# Display cloning doesn't work anymore (nVidia)

Tags: nvidia, display

I used to clone my laptop's display to an external monitor by just typing `disper -c` in a terminal. One of the recent updates broke this functionality. It now says

```
$ disper -c
displays share no common resolution
```

A friend of mine has experienced exactly the same problem, so I don't think is has to do with my particular display configuration.

Does anybody know what happened and whether there's a workaround? It's specially annoying given that it used to work fine before.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the latest nvidia drivers, then I'm sorry to inform you that there is no fix currently. There is a problem with xrandr + the latest drivers (30x.xx) where dual monitor setups either don't work, or do so poorly, and cloning is just completely ruined.